# Какой знак употребить — вопросительный или восклицательный?

Tags: пунктуация

> Кто бы мог подумать, что он кажется вором(?)

Какой знак тут правильней поставить и почему?

Answer (score 1):

1. Правильно написать в предложении "...что он **о**кажется вором".
2. Выбор знака, думаю, зависит от контекста и сопутствующих ему авторских эмоций и интонации.
   Вот некоторые примеры.

*Кто бы мог подумать, что любимым героем современных подростков окажется Робинзон Крузо?* (из журнала "Вокруг света")

*А я решила... что он явно передумает, если подобрать правильную мотивацию. Кто бы мог подумать, что он окажется таким упрямым!* (К. Хьюит. Попроси меня остаться)

*Я усмехнулась, пожав плечами. Надо же. Кто бы мог подумать, что он окажется таким романтиком* (А. Селиверстова. Хранители).

*А кто бы мог подумать, что НАТО полезет на восток? Кто бы мог подумать, что холодная война окажется перманентной? Кто бы мог подумать, что Вашингтон в конце концов захочет прилепить к НАТО Грузию и Украину?* (из статьи О. Чувакина)

*Кто бы мог подумать, что за солнечным утром в Москву придет метель?!* (из метеоновостей)

Comment: А как насчет правил, нарушать будем?  Где разрешение от Лопатина,  или Розенталя,  или хотя бы от кого.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, "окажется".
Можно вопросительный, можно восклицательный, можно "?!", можно даже точку.

Answer (score 0):

**Кто бы мог подумать, что он окажется вором?**

Здесь ставится **вопросительный знак, это риторический вопрос.**

**Восклицательный знак** ставится в том случае, если выражаются **эмоции**, тогда местоименные слова в начале предложения играют роль частицы

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

**Вопросительный знак ставится** в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится **и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной:** Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия? (Остр.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=89#pp89

Всегда является восклицательным предложение, имеющее в своем составе слова что за, как, какой и т. п.: Что за чудесный человек мой друг! (Т.); Как вы побледнели! (П.); Какая необыкновенная была эта девушка на грузовике! (Ф.)
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88